# Python type annotations in parameters for functions

Tags: python

I know that python can annotate types in a function, so something like

```
def sum(x: int, y: int) -> int:
    return x + y
```

can be possible.

what if I want to pass in a function as an argument? Python gives me an error when I try to do that.

so for example,

```
def another_func():
    #some func

def sum(another_func: **Function**, x: int, y: int) -> int:
    #some func
```

the bolded part does work. How can I annotate function types?

Answer (score 3):

```
from typing import Callable
def sum(another_func: Callable, x: int, y: int) -> int: [...]
```